# Where can I find the version of scipy python package used in QGIS Lyon 2.12?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.10, qgis-2.12, voronoi-thiessen, scipy.spatial

I am using QGIS Pisa 2.10. I want to use the Voronio class of scipy.spatial in QGIS python console. QGIS Pisa has 0.11 version of scipy package. This package doesn't have Voronoi class. I even tried upgrading it. But since I am in windows environment, the Scipy.exe installer is unable to detect the python inside Pisa (C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27). Instead it is always referring to the Python installed at the user level (C:\Python27_32Bit) from the registry.

If the version of scipy used in QGIS Lyon is greater than 0.11 then, I will uninstall Pisa and install the Lyon.

Answer (score 3):

I have QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon and used the following in the **Python Console** to find out which `scipy` version I have installed (QGIS was installed using the [OSGeo4W Network Installer package](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)):

```
>>>import scipy
>>>print scipy.__version__
0.14.0
```

Comment: @Tony - Most welcome buddy :)